# Zurb Foundation: How To center ul menu lists in a DIV

Tags: html, zurb-foundation, center, inline

I have been having a hard time trying to place un-ordered inline elements in the center of a div.

I need help to do this.

```
    <div class="column">
<ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
  <li>
    <a href="#">For Sale</a>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1A</a></li>
      <!-- ... -->
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Vehicles</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Classes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Real Estate</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sevices</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Personals</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Another Way which didn't work.
By employing the float-center rule

For Sale

Item 1A

```
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Vehicles</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Classes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Real Estate</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sevices</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Personals</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

It's easier to shift ul elements to center of the DIV when using raw html/css.
The menu items shift to the left of the DIV when I add zurb foundation tags/rules.I have tried all means to get these centered, but I can't.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your case is that the ul element has a display property with a value of block. This causes the width of the ul to be as large as the parent's div.

You can add a class to the ul element that changes the **display** property to **inline-block** and add the **text-center** class to the parent div to center the content.

Here is a link to codepen http://codepen.io/MKallivokas/pen/ONbYYV:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="column text-center">
<ul class="dropdown menu custom-menu" data-dropdown-menu>
  <li>
    <a href="#">For Sale</a>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1A</a></li>
      <!-- ... -->
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Vehicles</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Classes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Real Estate</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sevices</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Personals</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.custom-menu {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you use `.text-center` class or `margin: 0 auto;`